# Integrate Office 2010 (PKC Version) into Windows for deployment?

Tags: microsoft-office, deployment, sysprep, fog

I'm having a hard time preparing my Windows 7 master image (sysprep), which will be deployed to various notebooks. Unfortunately we've only bought Office 2010 Home & BUsiness PKC (Product Key Card), which means, I can install Office only after entering a valid product key.

Is there a way to pre-install Office 2010 to the master image and let the users enter their keys AFTER the deployment?

I was thinking of using a Trial Version, but that's only 90 days valid.

Comment: And it did not work with OPK? http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/installation/downloads/Pages/office_2010_opk.aspx